# using rbind gives error warning about factor levels

Tags: r

```
fxrates <-rbind(fxrates,c("EODMRS","USD","M",1,1,"17-APR-2019",1))
```

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "USD") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated

Guys, Do you know why second cell (with USD) is not generated?

Comment: Change the `factor` columns to `character` and it would be fine i..e `i1 <- sapply(fxrates, isfactor); fxrates[i1] <- lapply(fxrates[i1], as.character)`

Answer (score 1):

We can change the `factor` columns to `character` and `rbind` with a `list` of values as the types can be different and `vector` (constructed with`c`) can store only a single type

```
i1 <- sapply(fxrates, is.factor)
fxrates[i1] <- lapply(fxrates[i1], as.character)
rbind(fxrates,list("EODMRS","USD","M",1,1,"17-APR-2019",1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still I have the same error with this formula :/

Comment: @KennyR  That error shouldn't happen because it is converted to `character`

Comment: @KennyR Sorry there was a typo. `isfactor` should be `is.factor`

Comment: @KennyR  Thank you for pointing that out.  I was going to test it with `iris` and then I found the typo

Answer (score 0):

How about using `add_row` in `dplyr` package?

```
fxrates <- dplyr::add_row(
    fxrates,
    x1 = "EODMRS", x2 = "USD", x3 = "M", x4 = 1, x5 = 1, x6 = "17-APR-2019", x7 = 1)
)
```

Those x1...x7 should be replaced with proper column names.